# SolrJ CloudSolrClient connection error

Tags: apache, indexing, solr, solrj

I am struggling with indexing using Solrj.

I want to use SolrCloud and I set my connection like this :

```js
SolrClient client = new CloudSolrClient.Builder().withSolrUrl("http://localhost:8983/solr/collectioname").build();
```

And I have this error. I checked evruwhere before posting here but I can't resolve it

```js
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Couldn't initialize a HttpClusterStateProvider (is/are the Solr server(s), [http://localhost:8983/solr/collectioname], down?)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient$Builder.build(CloudSolrClient.java:1496)
 at indexsolr.<init>(indexsolr.java:29)
 at LoadData.toIndex(LoadData.java:100)
 at LoadData.loadDocuments(LoadData.java:72)
 at IndexLaunch.main(IndexLaunch.java:12)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/collectioname: Expected mime type application/octet-stream but got text/html. <html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"/>
<title>Error 404 Not Found</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/collectioname/admin/collections. Reason:
<pre>    Not Found</pre></p>
</body>
</html>

 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.executeMethod(HttpSolrClient.java:607)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:255)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient.request(HttpSolrClient.java:244)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.request(SolrClient.java:1219)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClusterStateProvider.fetchLiveNodes(HttpClusterStateProvider.java:189)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpClusterStateProvider.<init>(HttpClusterStateProvider.java:64)
 at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient$Builder.build(CloudSolrClient.java:1494)
 ... 4 more
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the previous answer, SolrJ uses the URL without the collection name in it (which I should have pointed out more directly):

```
final String solrUrl = "http://localhost:8983/solr";
return new HttpSolrClient.Builder(solrUrl)
    .withConnectionTimeout(10000)
    .withSocketTimeout(60000)
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

For SolrCloud you need to use CloudSolrClient. Depending on Solr version you are using you can create object of [CloudSolrClient](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_5_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/CloudSolrClient.html) or you can use [CloudSolrClient.Builder](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_5_0/solr-solrj/org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/CloudSolrClient.Builder.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.
Solr cloud just needs to take a list of urls as a parameter and not just a String url.

```
private static final String BASE_SOLR_URL = "http://localhost:8983/solr"; 
// or initialize a list of solr instances urls 

@Bean(name = "solrCloudClient")
public static CloudSolrClient getCloudConnection() {
    System.out.println("----Initializing cloud Solr Connection---");
    List<String> solrCloudUrls = Arrays.asList(BASE_SOLR_URL); // or list of urls

    CloudSolrClient client = new CloudSolrClient.Builder(solrCloudUrls).build();
    client.setParser(new XMLResponseParser());
    return client;
}
```